# Place specific item of Array at the end

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, combobox

I have an array coming from the database that sorted alphabetically just like this:

> ['Algebra', 'Others', 'Physics']

Now, what I want is when I populate my `ComboBox` the `'Other'` word will be place at the end of the array. Any idea on how to achieve that? So the array would be like this:

> ['Algebra', 'Physics', 'Others']

Comment: Uhm ... filter out "Others" from the initial array, and then append "Others" at the end of the resulting array?

Comment: Add the `Others` option only after sorting.

Comment: How is your database bound to the combobox? Please post some code to see what you're trying to do, and what actually happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about  using Linq OrderBy .

```
var arr = new[] { "Algebra", "Others", "Physics" };
arr = arr.OrderBy(e => e == "Others").ToArray();
```

Comment: Yep. As simple as this.

Comment: It works because `OrderBy` is guaranteed to be "stable" (written in the MSDN), so the order of the non-"Others" elements remains the same at the end of the sorting.

Answer (score 3):

Add "Others" to your combobox after populating combobox

```
comboBox1.Items.Remove("OTHERS");
comboBox1.Items.Add("OTHERS");
```

Comment: I updated my question. The array is coming from the database. :)

Comment: Populate the combobox, remove "Others" and add "Others", I updated the code

Answer (score 2):

`Others` has an exception in your items and you know that. so just code it

```
if (items.Contains("Others"))
{
    items.Remove("Others");
}
items.Add("Others"); // place this inside if statement if `Others` should not be added 
                     // and can only be moved to end of array.
```

Answer (score 1):

While I would use the solution proposed by others (simply add "Others" at the end manually), if you really want to sort the array:

```
var arr = new[] { "Algebra", "Others", "Physics" };

Array.Sort(arr, (p, q) => {
    if (p == "Others") {
        return q == "Others" ? 0 : 1;
    }

    if (q == "Others") {
        return -1;
    }

    return StringComparer.CurrentCulture.Compare(p, q);
});
```

(I create a string comparison function that handles "Others" in a special way, and consider it to be the "greatest" string)

Comment: That's the best solution so far. Just sort it before publishing it to the control.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
string[] str = {"Algebra", "Others", "Physics"};
var list = str.Where(c => c != "Others").OrderBy(c => c).ToList();
list.Add("Others");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just manually put 'Others' at the end of your array?

```
string[] list = { "Algebra", "Physics", "Others" };
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(list);
```

[image]

Comment: The OP says the array comes from the database and is alphabetically sorted, so manually creating the array doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks. That bit about coming from a database was not in his post originally when I put my answer in! Since there are updated answers now that will do the job, I don't think there is much point updating mine. :)

Comment: Fair enough. I don't like it when people edit their questions so that it invalidates existing answers. They should append such changes.